# How can I scale specific applications to work with a 4K high-dpi monitor?

Tags: display-resolution, scaling

I'm new to Linux so please be nice...

I have a 4K monitor, and I have it set up to scale the Ubuntu interface so that it's not so tiny, but some specific applications don't work with this (like Play on linux or Steam). On Windows 10 normally I'd just open the program's properties and change its scaling behavior but I don't know if there's that option on Ubuntu (and if there is, where).

How would I change the scaling of individual applications, not system-wide?

Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: 4K is a complete mess on Ubuntu, sadly. You're gonna have a hard time doing much. [This ArchWiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI) covers a bit of the HiDPI issue, and does offer workarounds for some apps. Really though, we just need to wait for better HiDPI support (through Wayland and through native apps).